# splitting single line into multiple line in numbering format using awk

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, awk

I'm trying to split the value using awk command into three parts. Need help to break into 3.

Content = `1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %`

I want the above content to break into 3 lines in a numbering system.

Sample output required :

```
1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 
2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 
3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %
```

I have tried by the following commands :

```
echo $content | awk -F"3. " '{ print $2 }'
```

and i get

```
31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %
```

Similarly for others, But still failed to get sample output in proper numbering format as shown above.

Can any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sed` instead:

```
sed "s#[^^]\([0-9]\.\) #\n\1 #g"
```

Example:

```
[~/Desktop]
==> echo "1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %" | sed "s#[^^]\([0-9]
\.\) #\n\1 #g"
1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 %
2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 %
3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %
```

Answer (score 6):

The `%` symbol looks like a good candidate to split on. Try:

```
sed 's/% /%\n/g'
```

Testing:

```
echo "1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %" | sed 's/% /%\n/g'
```

Results:

```
1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 %
2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 %
3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\s)/\n$1/g'
```

tested:

```
> echo "1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %" | perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\s)/\n$1/g'

1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 
2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 
3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %
```

Comment: This works on Macs, where sed treats \n and n as the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo "1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %" | awk '{n = split($0,array,"%"); for (i = 0; i < n-1; ++i){gsub("^ ","",array[i+1]);print array[i+1]" %",i}}'
```

Comment: unwanted leading blank for the last two lines looks like last two are sub lines of first one..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't really test my code out. I've made changes, it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears fixed in number of elements.

```
{
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7
    print $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14
    print $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21
}
```

Useful if you have to do anything with the data other than printing it.

Answer (score 1):

For a POSIX-compliant answer that works on Mac:

```
sed -E $'s/ ([0-9]+\\. )/\\\n\\1/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 % 2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 % 3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %" | sed -E $'s/ ([0-9]+\\. )/\\\n\\1/g'
1. 11683 (<server01>: du.size[/,free] : 0.5 %
2. 21683 (<server02>: du.size[/,free] : 1.5 %
3. 31683 (<server03>: du.size[/,free] : 3.5 %
```

## How it works

### `-E`

Turns on nicer regex syntax, so that we have `+` to match one or more of something, and we only need `(...)` for capturing groups instead of `\(...\)`.

### `s/.../.../g`

The `s/` means to do a string replacement. `/g` means don't stop after the first replacement on a line.

### `/ ([0-9]+\. )/`

Matches `' 2. '` and `' 3. '`, and captures `'2. '` and `'3. '` for later use. Including the leading space before the capture group lets us avoid adding an extra newline before the `'1.'`, since `'1.'` is at the beginning of the line and has no space before it. The trailing space inside the capture filters out things like `'1.5'`.

### `/\n\1/`

`\n` is a newline, and `\1` is the first parenthesis capture group.

### `$'...'` and extra backslashes

The POSIX way to give sed a newline is to put a `\` and then an actual newline character:

```
$ echo 'a#b' | sed 's/#/\
/'
a
b
```

Linux is special, because GNU extended sed to recognize `\n`, but in other versions of sed (like on Mac), `\n` is not interpreted as a newline, and we need to use the POSIX format. However, to make this a one-liner, we used `$'...\\\n...'` which tells the shell to interpret escape sequences. First, `\\` encodes a `\`, and then `\n` does the newline.